# Guardar password nuevo usuario Laravel collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy enviando un formulario en laravel collective con los siguientes campos:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre ') }}
    {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('lastname', 'Apellidos') }}
    {{ Form::text('lastname', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'lastname']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Correo') }}
    {{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
    {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'password' ) ) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
</div>
```

y en mi controlador en el metodo store tengo esto

```
   $user = User::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('users.edit', $user->id)->with('info', 'Usuario creado con éxito');
```

Pero la password enviada por el formulario no me la encripta, sino que la guarda tal cual como es enviada por el formulario.

Comment: ¿Es un nuevo usuario el que estás almacenando?

Comment: Si, Esque necesito poder crear usuarios con su nombre apellido correo y password mediante un formulario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomado (y adaptado) del código de Laravel 5.7:

```
    User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'lastname' => $request->lastname,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
```

Al comienzo de tu controlador debes incluir el facade Hash:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Puedes ver más información en el archivo app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder